# How can I find out what rule produces an error?

Tags: php, rules, phpcodesniffer

I'm setting up [PHP CodeSniffer](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer) as a linter for my code and I have an error which I want to ignore.

In order to do that, I should be able to put the line `// phpcs:ignore Name.Of.The.Rule` before the line that is an exception to that rule.

Unfortunately, I don't know how I can find which of the rules I have to ignore. Is there a way to display the rule producing the error?

For now, I searched the error message in my `vendor` folder, resulting in 4 different entries. I'm not sure I know which is the one called.

The error summary looks like that:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
FOUND 1 ERROR AFFECTING 1 LINE
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 14 | ERROR | Method name "ActivityRules::is_after" is not in camel
    |       | caps format
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I would love to have something like that:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FOUND 1 ERROR AFFECTING 1 LINE
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 14 | ERROR | Method name "ActivityRules::is_after" is not in camel   | SomeStandard.Category         
    |       | caps format                                             | .NameOfTheSniff.RuleCalled
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**EDIT:**

I don't need you to tell me it's `PSR1.Methods.CamelCapsMethodName.NotCamelCaps`, I know how to find the rule by hand the hard way, by trial and error. I'd like to know if there is an easy way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

## Use `phpcs -s`

The output of phpcs --help includes the available options:

```
phpcs --help
...
 -s    Show sniff codes in all reports
...
```

The 'Show sniff codes in all reports' option results in this output format:

```text
➜  /tmp phpcs -s example.php

FILE: /private/tmp/example.php
----------------------------------------------------------------------
FOUND 1 ERROR AFFECTING 1 LINE
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 14 | ERROR | [ ] Method name "ActivityRules::is_after" is not in camel caps format
    |       |     (PEAR.NamingConventions.ValidFunctionName.NotCamelCaps)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Time: 30ms; Memory: 6MB

➜  /tmp
```

Which is hopefully close enough to what you're looking for here.

Comment: I knew there was an option for that. Thanks!